# Load full Unity project structure to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, unity-game-engine

I am new in stackoverflow so please excuse any mistakes in the format. I did my research and couldn't find much so here it goes.

As the title states I would like to know if it is possible to load the full project structure into VS, not only the script folders/files. I would like to use the Team Services Repository to save my project and work along with a small team, hoping to go indie.

I have searched around the options in VS and Unity but there was no option like that. Loading the folders manually into the project creates a huge list of meta files and almost hogs down the whole system while the process continues. Any input on the issue would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Visual studio can load a solution file `.sln` or it can load a proj file `.csproj`.  Do you have those file types in your Unity project?  If yes, add the projects to your VS 2015 Solution or just open the Unity `.sln`.  If no, you'll have to make a new solution and projects in VS and add the assets manually.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the process and due to the connection Unity and Visual Studio has now with the Visual Studio Tools for Unity it actually creates a Solution and Project automatically. The problem is that it loads only the folders and files that contain code. All the other folders that exist in the Unity project folder structure are left out. As I mentioned in the question, manually throwing in the folders doesn't help much because in that case you get flooded with the unity meta files and VS cannot automatically follow changes in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any option to configure this in Visual Studio and with Tools for Unity unless you add these folders/files to the project manually.

And you mentioned you'd like to use Team Service Repository to save the project, you can also use [tf command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) for TFVC repository or [Git command](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html) for Git repository to add your files to VSTS Repository.

Comment: I was afraid it was going to be like that!!! Well manual it is then. Thank you very much for the information.